# numpy.reciprocal returns different values when called repeatedly

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I have a numpy array `ssh_sum`:

```
>>> ssh_sum
array([[ 0.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  2.]])
```

I wanted to compute the element-wise reciprocal values in this array. Numpy returns different values when I call np.reciprocal repeatedly:

```
>>> ssh_sum
array([[ 0.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  2.]])
>>> np.reciprocal(ssh_sum, where=(ssh_sum > 0.))
array([[  6.90326535e-310,   5.00000000e-001,   1.00000000e+000,
          0.00000000e+000,   1.07034283e-296,   1.33666925e+241],
       [  4.74783847e-309,   1.45260789e-296,   1.00000000e+000,
          5.00000000e-001,   2.13436228e-287,  -3.13188338e-294],
       [  4.85105226e-309,   1.08690709e+171,   4.09521901e+149,
          1.00000000e+000,   2.82730247e-311,   5.00000000e-001]])
>>> np.reciprocal(ssh_sum, where=(ssh_sum > 0.))
array([[ inf,  0.5,  1. ,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  1. ,  0.5,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  1. ,  inf,  0.5]])
>>> np.reciprocal(ssh_sum, where=(ssh_sum > 0.))
array([[  6.90326535e-310,   5.00000000e-001,   1.00000000e+000,
          0.00000000e+000,   1.07034283e-296,   1.33666925e+241],
       [  4.74783847e-309,   1.45260789e-296,   1.00000000e+000,
          5.00000000e-001,   2.13436228e-287,  -3.13188338e-294],
       [  4.85105226e-309,   1.08690709e+171,   4.09521901e+149,
          1.00000000e+000,   2.82730247e-311,   5.00000000e-001]])
>>> np.reciprocal(ssh_sum, where=(ssh_sum > 0.))
array([[ inf,  0.5,  1. ,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  1. ,  0.5,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  1. ,  inf,  0.5]])
```

Any idea what's going on here? I'm using Python 3.4.5 and numpy 1.13.3.

Comment: If you need a workaround, there's always; `m = ssh_sum > 0 ; ssh_sum[m] = 1 / ssh_sum[m]`

Comment: thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ your second comment saved the day

Comment: Can you upgrade to 1.14? If this is a bug in your version of numpy, or an install problem with your copy of numpy, who knows whether it will affect anything else you're relying on?

Comment: I just upgraded to 1.14, and the behavior is now consistent across calls, but instead of leaving 0 values at zero it's still setting them to some garbage like 4.85105226e-309

Comment: Maybe it's my CPU --- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz , microcode 0xb00001b

Comment: 4.05e-309 is pretty close to 0—as in more than close enough for `np.isclose` with defaults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not just `reciprocal`; the issue occurs with any use of the `where` argument.  I've been able to reproduce the issue with the master branch of numpy (`np.__version__` is `'1.15.0.dev0+c093997'`), with functions such as `abs`, `sign`, `add`, `subtract`, etc.

If you read the docstrings of the numpy "ufuncs" carefully and interpret them correctly, you'll see that the behavior is not a bug.  Here are the relevant descriptions from the `numpy.reciprocal` docstring:

```
out : ndarray, None, or tuple of ndarray and None, optional
    A location into which the result is stored. If provided, it must have
    a shape that the inputs broadcast to. If not provided or `None`,
    a freshly-allocated array is returned. A tuple (possible only as a
    keyword argument) must have length equal to the number of outputs.
where : array_like, optional
    Values of True indicate to calculate the ufunc at that position, values
    of False indicate to leave the value in the output alone.
```

Note, in particular:

- `where` says "values
  of False indicate to leave the value in the output alone."
- `out` says "If not provided or `None`,
  a freshly-allocated array is returned."

You did not provide an `out` argument, so a new array is allocated by your call to `reciprocal`.  The contents of this array are not initialized;  the array holds whatever happened to be in the allocated memory.  When you use the `where` argument, only those positions in the output where `where` is True are assigned values.  Positions where `where` is False are not touched, so they hold whatever random stuff was there when the array was allocated.  For floating point output, the random stuff in the output might be `0.0`, `4.85105226e-309`, or any other random values.

To use the `where` argument the way you intended, you should also provide your own `out` argument, initialized with the values you want in the output where `where` is False.  In your case, you should pass in an array of zeros:

```
In [84]: ssh_sum
Out[84]: 
array([[0., 2., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 2.]])

In [85]: out = np.zeros_like(ssh_sum)

In [86]: np.reciprocal(ssh_sum, where=ssh_sum > 0.0, out=out)
Out[86]: 
array([[0. , 0.5, 1. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 1. , 0.5, 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 1. , 0. , 0.5]])

In [87]: out
Out[87]: 
array([[0. , 0.5, 1. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 1. , 0.5, 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 1. , 0. , 0.5]])
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks. I assume the reason I couldn't reproduce it was because my Mac automatically allocated a block of 0s.